# On Ubuntu Eclipse workspace not launching

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new on Ubuntu and android.  When I am trying to open my eclipse it shows a popup message saying workspace/home/promaster/workspace is in use.  Even when I change the absolute path it show the same popup message.

Comment: Try to run your eclipse from the `terminal` and see what error occured

Comment: are you opening two or more eclipse? or have another eclipse open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If eclipse crashed and left it's lock file behind (that is, you are sure no one is running eclipse elsewhere with that workspace / you've rebooted) you can remove the lock file.

```
rm -f /home/promaster/workspace/.metadata/.lock
```

You can also run eclipse with

```
eclipse -clean
```

Comment: now my eclipse is opening , how can i add android sdk in it

Comment: "Window > Android SDK Manager"

Answer (score 0):

Click file and try switch workspace, click other and write your new path. It's all.

Comment: now my eclipse started on ubntu, now how can i add android sdk on it?

Comment: which ide do you use? eclipse adt-bundle or android studio?

Comment: i have downloaded adt bundle in which i have 2 files eclipse and android sdk but eclipse which i am using now it comes with ubntu software centre so how can i use android sdk in it